# Case statement with variables and user input

Tags: bash, loops, raspberry-pi, case

How do I use a case statement with variables?

I'm working on a bash script that logs simple information and saves it into csv file.
The whole script is like this: you have options to choose from (using case statement) and that will be logged to a file. At the point where I'm at, there's a prompt asking user about the quantity. In the log it will either be minus or plus. So if I take something out in the log it needs to say minus one item (-1) and if I bring something back it should be +1 or +2  or whatever the quantity is.

In the end I would like to use a pin pad where you have buttons <kbd>0-9</kbd> and <kbd>#</kbd> and <kbd>*</kbd>.
I'd like to use as an option buttons <kbd>*</kbd> for minus and button <kbd>#</kbd> for plus (I know I shouldn't but apparently if you comment them out, it does seem to work).

So for example if a user presses <kbd>*</kbd> then the user needs to press a number which will be the quantity of items. But if the user presses the wrong button, I want the script to ignore it and show the options of <kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>#</kbd> again.

In the very end like I've mentioned I need it all to be a variable that I can echo to that log.

I started writing it, because someone helped me with something similar, but things I tried didn't work out.

Here's just the idea of where I'm trying to go:

```
#! /bin/bash


minus="-"
plus="+"

echo "Press * for minus"
echo "Press # for plus"
echo "And then enter the quantity"

read -r choice
#And then comes case I guess.
```

Comment: please update the question with the *`things I tried didn't work out`*, otherwise it looks like you want us to write the entire set of code for you; also ... can the user enter a multi-digit answer (eg, `23`) or are they limited to entering a single digit at a time? a `read` requires the user to hit `<return_or_enter>` to tell `read` when the data entry is complete sooo, does the user have to hit `<return_or_enter>` or do you want `read` to process each single key press as a separate entry (eg, `read -n1`)?

Comment: Not at all. I only skipped that, because I'm embarrassed about my code that doesn't work:

Comment: ``` Think of it as a log that is important for like a warehouse. So yes, if someone takes 67 of items, log needs to have this -67 items echoed to it. The return or enter bid is already soreted out. Like the last line of the script will look like... Out characters. I'll Come back.

Comment: So there are other $(things) like variables that work earlier in the script. But in the end, I think the script will end with the line like this: echo $var1thatworked $var2thatworkier $userNumber $thingsI'mstrugglingWith >> mylog.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do

  echo "Press * for minus"
  echo "Press # for plus"
  echo "And then enter the quantity"

  read -r choice </dev/tty

  case $choice in

    '*')    # user input is 'minus' only
      read -r qty </dev/tty    # prompt user to input qty
      if [[ $qty =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]    # if qty input is only numbers
      then
        echo "-$qty" >> mylog.csv
        break    # break the loop after valid input
      else
        echo "INVALID INPUT" >&2
        # do not break loop
      fi
    ;;

    '#')    # user input is 'plus' only
      read -r qty </dev/tty
      if [[ $qty =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
      then
        echo "+$qty" >> mylog.csv
        break
      else
        echo "INVALID INPUT" >&2
      fi
    ;;

    '*'[0-9]*)    # user input is 'minus' followed by at least 1 number
      qty=${choice/#'*'}    # qty is choice without leading symbol
      if [[ $qty =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
      then
        echo "-$qty" >> mylog.csv
        break
      else
        echo "INVALID INPUT" >&2
      fi
    ;;

    '#'[0-9]*)    # user input is 'plus' followed by at least 1 number
      qty=${choice/#'#'}
      if [[ $qty =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
      then
        echo "+$qty" >> mylog.csv
        break
      else
        echo "INVALID INPUT" >&2
      fi
    ;;

    *)    # any other input or no input
      echo "INVALID INPUT" >&2
      # do not break loop
    ;;

  esac

done
```

Comment: This is unbelievable... 

But if you don't mind. When I uncomented #done, it returned this:
`line 63: syntax error near unexpected token `done'`

Comment: If you want to loop it, you need to uncomment the line near the top also, `while true; do`

Comment: I'm overwhelmed a bit and I've missed it. I wanted to loop it if a user makes the wrong inut. So for example if the user enters nnumber two instead of * or # then the script will prompt options again - else - it will just move on and log values. Is there a way?

Comment: I edited the code so that now it should do what you want it to do. If this is the solution you are looking for, I'd appreciate if you "accepted" my answer

Comment: If you don't mind:
Why have you used /dev/tty here? I tried to read about that, but I'm not sure if I understand it correctly.
Same question about >&2. Why are they important?

Not to add so many answers, I just want to say, that I would never figure it out myself in a milion years. I would never think that so much code is needed. Thank you for taking time, I relly appreciate this!

Comment: `>&2` redirects the `echo` text to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. This is best practice to do when coding error messages. Imagine if you have a script that is supposed to echo a value upon successful completion, that value would be output to `stdout`. You could store that value in a variable or pipe it to another process...but you wouldn't want to store or pipe an error message if the script was not successful. `stderr` is displayed in the terminal but will not be piped or stored. Redirecting errors to `stderr` with `>&2` separates  the meaningful, valuable output from the errors/debugging.

Comment: `</dev/tty` tells `read` to only accept input from the terminal. `read` can also be used to accept input from `stdin`. It wasn't absolutely necessary to specify `</dev/tty` in this code, but it is best practice to do so if you intend for user input only, especially if you are working with loops (in which the shell will sometimes assume you want `stdin` and bypass the user input)

Comment: One other thing I should mention: in the logging code, `echo "$qty" >> mylog.csv`, I have written it so that the log file is appended (`>>`) with the new addition/subtraction value every time. If you would rather the log be overwritten each time, change the `>>` to a single `>`